# MSGraph paging with application instead of delegate access token does not work

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to list all available rooms within my tenant using msgraph api.

```
/places/microsoft.graph.room
```

Using Graph explorer and my regular user everything works and i can paginate using `$skip` and `$top`.

In my actual implementation i use an access token requested using `client_credentials` instead of a delegated one. Here `$skip` + `$top` have no effect, while `$count=true` and `$filter` works as expected.

I also tried copying the delegate access token from graph explorer to my code and pagination magically worked. So its somewhat related to Application vs Delegate access token. I cant find any documentation about that behaviour.

Any way to actually have pagination with application permission? Also i guess not having the ability to paginate will also restrict the maximum rooms i could get to 100.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also repored this issue on github, seems to be fixed since a bit now